# MVC3 Moq account controller c# nUnit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I am trying to learn Moq but it is proving somewhat difficult.

If I want to implement some basic tests using nUnit and Moq for the account controller in a new MVC3 project, how would I go about it?

Im used to the entity framework. but not building interfaces for it.

edit:
I understand the theory of it all and the need to do it, but implementing it is confusing me

I have been using Entity Code generator (dbContext) to generate code I can use for interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a good test: When you register a new user, you want to make sure that he will be automatically signed in the site, so he doest not need to type his username and password again.

The test would be something like this:

```
public void AutomaticallySignedInAfterRegistering()
{
    var membershipService = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
    var formsService = new Mock<IFormsAuthenticationService>();
    RegisterModel newUser = new RegisterModel();
    newUser.UserName = "John"
    newUser.Email = "john@somewhere.com"
    newUser.Password = "p@ss";
    newUser.ConfirmPassword = "p@ss";

    membershipService.Setup(x => x.CreateUser("John", "p@ss", "john@somewhere.com")).Returns(MembershipCreateStatus.Success);

    AccountController controller = new AccountController();
    controller.FormsService = formsService.Object;
    controller.MembershipService = membershipService.Object;

    controller.Register(newUser);

    formsService.Verify(x => x.SignIn("John", false), Times.Once());
}
```

The key here is the Verify method. It works just like an Assert. In this case you are verifing that the method SignIn was called exactly once. This is an example of how to use mocks to check if the Account Controller is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good test to start with. One question though, what is the easiest way to create an interface for my EDMX entity framework entities? I have "DBContext Generator" installed, but it doesn't create interfaces, just classes for each entity (All the correct functions are there however)

Comment: Wrap the DbContext inside a custom class. I usually go for a interface like 'IDbContext' and a class named 'EntityFrameworkDbContext'. This class will internally use the DbContext created on the EDMX. All your controllers and services will make use of the IDbContext.